What is the exact definition of what it means for a prime to "split."
I am unsure if the meaning for the term "splits" is standardized. Given a prime ideal in a number ring and an extension of that number ring. Does the prime split if it is not inert or does it split only if it splits into two distinct factors?
Edit: I meant "at least two distinct factors"

The terminology is slightly ambiguous. Mostly, "splits" would mean that it becomes a product of (powers of?) primes "upstairs", as opposed to remaining prime. The "not remaining prime" is mostly the key feature.
Yes, if it "ramifies", in the extreme case meaning that it becomes a power of a prime upstairs, (which can only happen for finitely-many primes, so it's an anomalous case) some might say that it's not "split"... since there's only one prime upstairs. It's merely a convention, though. No mathematical content.
So, seriously, you can only tell from context.

Since you include "two distinct factors" as an option, I suspect you only have experience with quadratic fields.
When $K$ is a number field with degree $n$ over $\mathbf Q$ and $p$ is a prime number, the way $(p) = p\mathcal O_K$ decomposes in $\mathcal O_K$ is
$$
\mathfrak p_1^{e_1} \cdots \mathfrak p_g^{e_g}
$$
where the $\mathfrak p_i$ are distinct prime ideals and each $e_i$ is a positive integer. Let $f_i = f(\mathfrak p_i|p)$ be the residue field degree of $\mathfrak p_i$ over $p$, so $f_i \geq 1$. A fundamental relation among the $e_i$'s, $f_i$'s, and $g$ is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^g e_if_i = n, 
$$
so each $e_i$, $f_i$, and $g$ is at most $n$. That implies
(i) $g = n$ if and only if all $e_i$ and $f_i$ are $1$, which is equivalent to $(p) = \mathfrak p_1\cdots \mathfrak p_n$ (the ideal $(p)$ is a product of the largest possible number of distinct primes in an extension of degree $n$),
(ii) some $e_i$ is $n$ if and only if $(p) = \mathfrak p^n$ (the ideal $(p)$ is a power of a prime ideal with the largest possible multiplicity in an extension of degree $n$),
(iii) some $f_i$ is $n$ if and only if $(p) = \mathfrak p$ (the ideal $(p)$ is prime).
Property (i) is described by the phrase "$p$ splits completely in $K$", property (ii) is described by the phrase "$p$ is totally ramified in $K$", and property (iii) is described by the phrase "$p$ is inert in $K$".
Often the phrase "splits completely" is abbreviated to "splits".  I would not use the term "splits" in any other way, such as to mean "has at least two different prime factors".
When some $e_i > 1$, we say "$p$ is ramified in $K$".  In most number fields bigger than $\mathbf Q$, being ramified is not as specific as being totally ramified: that some $e_i > 1$ does not ordinarily mean $(p) = \mathfrak p^n$: when $K$ is a cubic field, a prime $p$ such that $(p) = \mathfrak p^2\mathfrak q$ is ramified while not being totally ramified.  Making an analogy with how polynomials with degree $n > 1$ factor in $\mathbf C[x]$, "ramified" is the same as having some multiple root while "totally ramified" is the same as having a single root with multiplicity $n$.
In the special case of quadratic fields, being ramified is the same as being totally ramified, just like a quadratic polynomial in $\mathbf C[x]$ has a multiple root if and only if it has a single root with multiplicity $2$. In a quadratic field, each prime is either split (completely), ramified, or inert, and those three options are mutually exclusive.
In number fields with degree greater than $2$, there might be primes that are not split, ramified, or inert: in a cubic field we might have $(p) = \mathfrak p\mathfrak q$ with $f(\mathfrak p|p) = 2$ and $f(\mathfrak q|p) = 1$. That has no analogue in $\mathbf C[x]$: a cubic does not decompose into irreducibles with degree $2$ and $1$.
